# & changes to %26 and = to %3D

Tags: php, html

I have a form that returns link on filter

```
<div class="item" style="float:right">
    <form class="ui icon input" name="search" action="" method="GET">   
        <input type="hidden" name="view" value="&user_id=156">                  
        <input type="search" name="filter" style="width:10em;" placeholder="Filter..">
        <i class="filter icon"></i>
    </form>
</div>
```

But it turns `&` in `%26` and `=` to `%3D`

I tried encode but it did not worked!
Please help

Tried :

```
        $query_string = 'objects&user_id=156';
        $a = urldecode($query_string);
```

Comment: Look at this [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Comment: you want to do something like url decode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php.  If you are just wanting `user_id` passed on the get string, change your hidden input to be called `user_id` with a value of `156`

Comment: Ok @Dexa and Pete trying that out!

Comment: @Dexa tryed this but nothing .   $query_string = 'objects&user_id=156';
                $a = urldecode($query_string);

Comment: IngusGraholskis you are using it wrong. Listen to @Pete and just set your hidden input to be called user_id with a value of 156

Comment: You may also need to take a look at this to see how to get your variables back from the querystring properly: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: I m slow and dumb  will take some time :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $query_string = 'objects%26user_id%3D156';
    $a = urldecode($query_string);
    var_dump($a);
```

remove var_dump after test

Comment: funny it still converts view=objects%26user_id%3D156 :( when i var_dump it works